# How to refer to the current thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading, ruby-1.9.3

When I want to refer to the current thread within the environment of a thread, several strategies seem to work:

- `t = Thread.new{p t}`
- `Thread.new{|t| p t}`
- `Thread.new{p Thread.current}`
- `Thread.new{p self}`

Are they all equivalent? Is there a reason to choose one over the others in a specific context?

Comment: weird im finding `self` doesnt refer to the thread: `Thread.new{ p self }.join` prints `main`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`self` will only work if you call it directly within the block passed to `Thread.new`, not if you call it from inside a method on another class which runs on that thread. If you use the `Thread.new { |t| p t}` approach, you will have to pass `t` around if you want to use it inside other methods which are run on that thread. But `Thread.current` works no matter where you call it from.

I would use `Thread.current`, because it makes it obvious what you're doing to anybody reading the code. Some readers might not know that if the `Thread.new` block takes a parameter, the new thread will be passed in to that parameter. `self` might not be 100% clear either. But any reader should immediately be able to understand what `Thread.current` means.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: `Thread.current` is most common approach to get current thread

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alex's answer, I noticed that `t = Thread.new{p t}` should be avoided. In some cases, when running the sub-thread is fast, the assignment to the variable `t` in the main thread might not be done by the time of its call inside the sub-thread, in which case, `t` is not defined (returning `nil`) or is something else.